# How do I reduce number of features without rebuilding the model?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language, naive-bayes

I'm pretty new to ML/NLP thus my question maybe naive. How do I reduce number of features without rebuilding the model for Naive Bayes Classification?

I'm using [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) to build the model to classify scientific articles to ~30 categories. I lemmatize text before processing. It brings the problem of excessive number of words/features. For 230K articles I have ~13M unique words :( So I thought what if I build model for ~5000 articles, sort probabilities of features for each class, take top 1000 and use only them. I could of course create white-list of words and rebuild the model but that would be slow.

Can I just take top N words, throw away the rest and then scale probabilities of new set or words to make the sum ~1.0 ? Would it be mathematically correct ? In case you wonder how it's implemented I wrote following code (in Scala)

```
var classifier: NaiveBayes = ... // Loaded valid model here

val numWords = 10000 // Number of words/features I want to use per class

val multinomials = classifier.getMultinomials

// Map of <index in alphabet> -> <probability>
val topProbabilities = multinomials.map { prob =>
  val probabilities = prob.getValues.map(Math.exp).zipWithIndex.sortBy(_._1).reverse
  probabilities.take(numWords).map(_.swap)
}

// Map of position of words in old alphabet to actual word and position in new alphabet
val alphMap = topProbabilities.flatMap(_.map(_._1)).distinct.zipWithIndex.map { case (oldId, newId) => (oldId, (newId, classifier.getAlphabet.lookupObject(oldId)) ) }.toMap

val alphabetNew = new Alphabet(alphMap.values.toArray.sortBy(_._1).map(_._2))

// Create array of doubles with scaled probabilities per each class
val newProbabilities = topProbabilities.map { pairs =>

  // I fill blanks for probabilities of missing words to minimal positive number
  val doubles = Array.fill(alphabetNew.size())(Double.MinPositiveValue)
  pairs.foreach{ case (oldPos: Int, v: Double) =>
    doubles(alphMap(oldPos)._1) = v
  }
  val factor = 1 / doubles.sum
  val doublesScaled = doubles.map(v => v * factor)
  new Multinomial.Logged(doublesScaled, alphabetNew)
}

var classifierNew = new NaiveBayes(classifier.getInstancePipe, classifier.getPriors, newProbabilities)

val words = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/home/expert/test_article.txt").getLines().mkString("").split(" ")
println(classify(classifier, words).getLabeling.getBestLabel)
println(classify(classifierNew, words).getLabeling.getBestLabel)
```

Sadly new "reduced" model misclasifies any article to first class :(

Comment: I think the fundamental question is valid - how do I reduce the number of words used?  You want to throw away words that are either in too many of the articles, or too few.  If I were doing this, I might look at a "qqnorm" lot of how many articles each word is in.  For each word in each of the 5000 articles, increment the count in a list containing the words.  The tails will tell you which ones you can exclude from either side, and maybe how many you could retain.  You might consider an RF for initial rules on those words in the 5k articles.

Comment: Out of curiosity which scientific articles dataset do you use, and do you use full text or abstract only?